# Login to geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I recently installed geoserver under macos. When I typed **http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/** in the navigator, I'm asked to inquire a login and a pwd. I remember giving the user_name of my machine while the process of the installation. Yet I don't remember setting any password. I don't know from where I can't get the password, assuming that the username fits the one I set the first time?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/gettingstarted/web-admin-quickstart/index.html):

> The default administration credentials are:
>
> > User name: admin
> >     Password: geoserver

Answer (score 0):

I did find out that the default authentication parameters are respectively : admin as username and geoserver as password. I did change them, so thank you anyway.